# problem to responsive images in wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, image, responsive

I have an issue with my images inside all the posts. They are not responsive
Take a look of one example
:https://fotografiaartistica.it/2018/10/luigi-ghirri-maestri-della-fotografia/
what can I do?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the body of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add below css to images in main style :

```
.post-entry img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- It looks like you have given inline width and height to image tag, Please remove that and apply css like my first answer

Answer (score -1):

Add this css in your active theme style.css.

```
.post .post-entry img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Don't use important for this. It's completely unnecessary and bad practice. Furthermore, `width: 100%` can pixellate. Use `max-width: 100%` instead along with images appropriate to the situation.

Answer (score -1):

I added your code by Additional CSS in the theme.

Is now working in the post, but not in others. look this one as an example:https://fotografiaartistica.it/2018/09/ralph-gibson-maestri-della-fotografia/
what's the problem?

Comment: Please do not use answers in place of comments.